# d3 bin using time threshold produces unequal bins

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```js
const data = [1573559497, 1590193694, 1574838137, 1580197649, 1589080449];

//time threshold
const timeThreshold = (n) => (_data, min, max) =>
  d3.scaleTime().domain([min, max]).ticks(n);

//bins
const bin = d3
  .bin()
  .value((d) => new Date(d * 1000))
  .thresholds(timeThreshold(10));

const boundaries = bin(data).map((bin) => ({
  x0: bin.x0,
  x1: bin.x1,
}));

console.log(boundaries);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```

The result produces 7 bins where the middle bins have a timespan of 1 month.

However:

- the first bin has x0 equal to `d3.min(data)`
- the last bin has x1 equal to `d3.max(data)`

I would like all bins to have an equal timespan, which in this case is 1 month.

Answer (score 2):

You may be out of luck if you want to use `d3.bin` for this. According to [the docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#bin_thresholds):

> The first bin.x0 is always equal to the minimum domain value, and the last bin.x1 is always equal to the maximum domain value.

However, since you want uniform bins, you can roll your own version relatively simply. See the example below.

```js
const data = [1573559497, 1590193694, 1574838137, 1580197649, 1589080449];
const dates = data.map((d) => new Date(d * 1000));

//time threshold
const scale = d3.scaleTime().domain(d3.extent(dates)).nice();
const ticks = scale.ticks(d3.timeMonth);

//boundaries
const boundaries = ticks.slice(1).map((t, i) => ({
  x0: ticks[i], // equivalent to i-1 in the original array
  x1: t,
}));

console.log(boundaries);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```